# Use DataContext to create schema in an existing blank database file?

Tags: .net, linq, schema, datacontext

With a [DataContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext_members(v=VS.100).aspx) and a *blank* file-based database that *already exists*,  is it possible to write the Data Context classes (i.e. the ones I added to the designer)  to create the db schema?

With a data context I only see the abilities to either:

- create a new database file and have its structure created at the same time,
- or to populate data into an existing database having preexisting schema.

I'm looking for a hybrid solution between those two worlds.

**Update 1** (more info): My proof that a preexisting db is not compatible with the Data Context [CreateDatabase()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.createdatabase.aspx) operation is this error

> Database
> 'C:...\App_Data\IntermediateData.mdf'
> already exists. Choose a different
> database name.

based on this code

```
using (IntermediateClassesDataContext intermediateContext = new IntermediateClassesDataContext(_getIntermediateConn())) {
    intermediateContext.CreateDatabase();
}
```

and this web.config entry (sanitized for SO) is what's being used:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="IntermediateData" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=W500\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Webapp\App_Data\IntermediateData.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"/>
```

... and the database mentioned already exists on disk with proper access permissions.

**Update 2** (clarification):

### Context and Reasoning = File permissions and security

I don't want to give permission to the user to write new files inside the website data directory (which CreateDatabase tries to do); however I don't mind if the user can write schema and data into a preexisting data file. If a viable solution doesn't exist I might cave in and open up permissions.

What I did to get here, was create a bunch of new classes on a blank DataContext canvas as seen below. Those represent the schema I want to persist to an existing blank database:

[alt text http://img8.imageshack.us/img8/5903/sampledm.png](http://img8.imageshack.us/img8/5903/sampledm.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd warn to stay away from CreateDatabase. Sounded great but if I recall it can't/doesn't create any associations/foreign keys.